# Bootstrap 4 center items only on small viewport, but no alignment on every other size?

Tags: css, button, text, alignment, center

I'm new to Bootstrap so I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm trying to make it so that a couple buttons and a tic tac toe board have no alignment (so just the way they are) on all viewport sizes, but once it hits small, they are centered.

I've tried to use `text-center` and `text-sm-center` but it does the opposite of what I want (apply to the smallest viewport and everything bigger, whereas I want it to apply to the smallest but nothing else). Is there a way to go about doing this? I've included screenshots of how I want it to look.

```
    <section class="container" id="game">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6" id="tic">
            <canvas id="square1" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
            <canvas id="square2" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
            <canvas id="square3" width="100" height="100"></canvas><br />

            <canvas id="square4" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
            <canvas id="square5" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
            <canvas id="square6" width="100" height="100"></canvas><br />

            <canvas id="square7" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
            <canvas id="square8" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
            <canvas id="square9" width="100" height="100"></canvas>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6" id="rules">
            <h2>RULES</h2>
            /* list of rules */
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <button id="undo" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Undo Move</button>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-6">
                <button id="new" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">New Game</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is how it looks with no alignment on a larger viewport
[image]

but when it gets to the smallest viewport, I want the tic tac to board and two buttons to align

[image]

Comment: This might help you? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zVaJjG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

text-center means all text will be centered, text-sm-center will center the text on small viewpoint and above, try using text-center and then text-sm-left.

This is because of that style of bootstrap class, same as col-md-12 etc work as a media query with a min-width, where everything that size and above gets assigned the css rule not that rule (breakpoint) only.

Comment: Awesome thank you! Would you mind explaining why text-sm-left gives it the effect of being centered on smaller viewports rather than just being aligned to the left?

Comment: text-sm-left will left align text on the small breakpoint, one a small/mobile phone breakpoint your actually using the xs breakpoint (this is just text-left) on bootstrap 4 and above. so text-left effects all display sizes (eg 0 px and above) tex-sm-left is just the left breakpoint and above.